# Run Macros in Lightning via javascript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, macros

We have used custom lightning component to categorize and show the macros on it. On selecting a macro, I need to run the macro from the component itself.

Is there a way to run the macro from lightning component?

PS: I was not able to use sforce.console.runmacro which we could use in Visualforce page.

Comment: That function does not exist. Have you looked at the docs for [`sforce.console.selectMacro(id);`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_selectmacro.htm) and [`sforce.console.runSelectedMacro();`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_runselectedmacro.htm) to run a macro?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand the [documentation here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=macros_run.htm&type=5),
Macros are only supported in the Classic Console and not in Lightning.

You could ask the SF Support to verify or falsify this assumption. The question about general availability is not Developer support IMOH, so you should get it answered even without premier support.